# How to make a contact form that sends me mails in Spring + thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

im currently working on a website and want to have a contact form which sends me the e-mail with the question. I found some tutorials but they aren't very clear. Anybody knows how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One might answer "Yes I do", what is your specific issue? Maybe you could try something and tell us where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

1. Serve the form
2. Handle form submission: get the user input and pass that to some service that send the mail

see this question for example: [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)

For the service, to send the mail, check out java-mail, see [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html) for example

---

=> community wiki

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723310/using-thymeleaf-template-for-sending-mail-with-spring?rq=1